# Yup validation for Postal code that starts with 0

Tags: reactjs, validation

postalCode: Yup.string()
.required('Please input data for this field.')
.min(6, 'The number must be 6 digits')
.matches(
/^([0-9]{6})*$/,
'Invalid postal code',
)

Need to optimize so that it can accept only numbers
and need to nullable.